# How can I show the Percentage Value On my Legends in Report (Pie Chart)

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm new to SQL Server. how can I add the values of my Pie Chart to the Legend next to the Series fields? In this case I want the percentage.

For example:

```
United States 43.2%
Canada 22%
etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer I use.

In the Series Proporties under Series Data you will find the Category field: (blank by default)

Enter what ever text you want and the keywords for the values you want displayed. Below are the values entered and the Legend display results.

```
Also Hispanic - (#VALY)    
Also Hispanic - (2156)

Also Hispanic - #VALY      
Also Hispanic - 2156

Also Hispanic - (#PERCENT{P1})  
Also Hispanic - (21.8%)

Also Hispanic - #PERCENT{P1}    
Also Hispanic - 21.8%
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239373%28SQL.100%29.aspx  check the section titled "To display percentage values in the legend of a pie chart "

Answer (score 0):

Had the same wish. I am charting number of staff in a quarter by staff category. I have a simple proc that takes a date (@EOQDate - start of quarter) and lists the staff . So I added a simple total in my SELECT SQL statement...

```
, COUNT(staffID) OVER (PARTITION BY @EOQDate)   AS StaffCount
```

then in SSRS design mode click on the category legend and on the bottom of the chart in the **Drop category fields here** section right-click on the category you dragged into this area and *select Category group properties...*

In the **Lable** box click the expression builder and build the expression you want to see. Obviously you need the existing category lable, in my case...

=Fields!StaffCategory.Value

Then add the percentage which is Count(Fields!staffID.Value)/Fields!StaffCount.Value

You'll need to turn it into a percentage, so my final expression looks like this...

=Fields!StaffCategory.Value & "  " & Format(Count(Fields!staffID.Value)/Fields!StaffCount.Value, "0.00 %")

And Wullah! category lable and percentage.

Answer (score -1):

We should be knowing the exact way of calculating the 43.2 to achieve this.

For example:

Total Number of Cycles: 20
Total Number of Cycles Used : 10 
Percentage of the Cycles: 10/20 * 100 =  50 %

Now I would write the expresssion to complete this Case:

=Sum(Fields!ID.Value, "Total_Number_Of_Cycles_Used") * 100 / Sum(Fields!ID.Value, "Total_Number_Of_Cycles") & "%"

"Total_Number_Of_Cycles_Used" and "Total_Number_Of_Cycles" are the two datasets created.

For some Percentages, sometimes we would not be requiring the decimals more than 2. We could achieve it by using.

=LEFT(FORMAT(Sum(Fields!ID.Value, "Total_Number_Of_Cycles_Used") * 100 / Sum(Fields!ID.Value, "Total_Number_Of_Cycles"))) & "%"

Your Query:

="United States" & Percentage Expresssion as Mentioned Above

Hope this Helped You.

Regards

GVS

Answer (score -1):

In the series label properties of Chart..set #LEGENDTEXT #PERCENT{#%;;""}

Regards,
Krishna